# Is it okay to use FontAwesome icons on a Material UI project in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, font-awesome

I am creating a react project and I'd like to know if it's okay to use FontAwesome icons on a ReactJS project that is using MaterialUI.

I tried to use the Material UI Icons and also use FontAwesome Icons but I thought that there's a repetition.

Answer (score -1):

React is completely flexible. You can use whatever you want, just don't forget about package sizes (which can get bad only in rare scenarios and certainly not with icons).